# How to import/export all collections of the MongoDB database using mongodb java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Is there any function to import and export all collections of mongodb database using java driver.? like there is `mongodump` and `mongorestore` using command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. These commands can be invoked only from command line. You might consider to fetch all the data from all collections but its expected to be slow.

You can read a [discussion around this here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/15v2xDwiw6A).

Answer (score 1):

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db sample
```

It  exacts with folder as dump with database name sample

```
mongorestore --db sample --verbose d:/dump/sample/
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about using the Java driver.

Answer (score 1):

(same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503928/it-is-possible-to-use-mongorestore-and-mongodump-command-from-java-or-javafx/35891000#35891000))

recently I've started a project called **mongodbdump-java-wrapper**  to wrap `mongodump.exe` and `mongorestore.exe` mongodb executable from java.

You could clone it from : [github project](https://github.com/boly38/mongodbdump-java-wrapper). This project includes integration tests (a way to know how implement backup/restore).

Comment: Thanks for github link!

Answer (score 0):

Well as of now, Mongo Java driver does not support this.

You can try invoking the mongoimport and mongorestore commands from Java Runtime. Like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongoimport -d <dbname> -h <>..");
```