# It is possible to use mongorestore and mongodump command from Java or JavaFx?

Tags: java, mongodb, javafx

I am new to JavaFX so here is a scenario:

- I have running Mongo as Windows service
- I have buttons in JavaFX stage for backup and restore databases in Mongo

It is possible to backup or restore database by putting code in `onClick` method of buttons? Can someone tell me how to do this or provide code for this?

- Path: `"Path to Store Database Backup in My Computer"`
- Method for backup: `public void bBackup() { /* Code for backup data */ }`
- Method for restore: `public void bRestore() { /* Code for restore data */ }`

Comment: Of course, not natively. You could use ProcessBuilder to call the according executables. But that's not too elegant. From my point of view, you can only reimplement the functionality, though I honestly doubt that this is reasonable from a performance point of view. It's not easy to achieve according performance with languages compiling to native code, and the challenges with Java will be even bigger.

Answer (score 3):

recently I've started a project called **mongodbdump-java-wrapper**  to wrap `mongodump.exe` and `mongorestore.exe` mongodb executable from java.

You could clone it from : [github project](https://github.com/boly38/mongodbdump-java-wrapper). This project includes integration tests (a way to know how implement backup/restore).