# Export mongo database from java

Tags: java, mongodb, javafx

I am creating an application in javafx as front end and mongodb as back end . My application has a menu item generate back up on clicking this menu item all the collections in database has to be back uped in form of csv files . I tried mongoexport in command prompt but **how could I export mongo database with help of java**

Comment: You can do that only if you invoke command line in Java. A similar question has already been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492008/how-to-import-export-all-collections-of-the-mongodb-database-using-mongodb-java

Comment: Thanks celia but accessing cmd through java helps only to execute batch files .It throws an error mongoexport is not a batch file .How can I solve this

Comment: Try the following:
`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.0\\bin\\mongoexport --db your_db --collection your_collection --out C:\\results.json");
        pr.waitFor();`

Comment: thanks celia its working

Comment: @Celia,  Is there any other option other than this

Comment: You can check the following [github project](https://github.com/boly38/mongodbdump-java-wrapper). Though, I don't know if it works properly.