# Can I run mongorestore command inside a groovy file?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, mongorestore

I have a groovy script which  drops a db and restores the db from an existing backup (SQL)

```
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dbSQLUrl, userName, password)
```

I passed all the required parameters and ran `sql.execute()` as below,

```
sql.execute(
        alter database dbName
        set offline with rollback immediate
        drop database dbName
       )


sql.execute(
    RESTORE DATABASE dbName
    FROM disk = 'C:\Backups'
    WITH REPLACE
)
```

All the above code works perfectly fine. I need to implement this for MongoDB as well. Is there an equivalent to `sql.execute()` in Mongo where I can run Mongo command like `mongorestore` in groovy file.

For Mongo I have the following code:

```
List credentials = []
List servers = []

credentials.push(MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUserName, mongoDBName, mongoPassword as char[]))
servers.push(new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort))

GMongoClient mongoClient = new GMongoClient(servers,credentials)
DB mongoDB = mongoClient.getDB(mongoDBName)
mongoDB.dropDatabase()
```

Now I need to run/include the following command inside my groovy file,
`mongorestore ~/backups/first_backup/`

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the most efficient way to do what you need, but you can call that command and wait for it to finish by adding this to your code:

```
String command = "mongorestore ${System.properties['user.home']}/backups/first_backup"
Process p = command.execute()
p.waitFor()
```

Comment: I have the below code,  String command = """mongorestore $dbBackUpPath"""Process p = command.execute()   , the basckup db is not created , whereas when I run the below code in command line , mongorestore /home/backups/test it works well.  I see the test db getting restored.

Comment: Did you add the `p.waitFor()`? You need some way to wait for that command to finish. To debug, add `println p.in.text + p.err.text` after `p = command.execute()` and see what the `mongorestore` is printing out.

Comment: My bad I was passing path wrongly , \home\backsups\test instead of /home/backups/test. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this can't be achieved using the MongoDB driver. These commands can be invoked only from command line (i.e. MongoDB shell). You may need to export the date as CSV and import the data into MongoDB programmatically which would be very slow.

Otherwise, you may need to execute the command using Groovy libs. Similar to the below Java command.

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongoimport -d  -h <>..");

[Similar question for Java Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492008/how-to-import-export-all-collections-of-the-mongodb-database-using-mongodb-java)

Comment: When I execute the above line from my script , it says "Process finished with exit code 0" but I don't see ant database getting restored, whereas when I run the following command from command line , "mongorestore /home/backups/test" , I see the db getting restored.

Comment: I wrote Runtime.getRuntime().exec("""mongorestore $dbBackUpPath""")

Comment: Have you tried with full absolute path of mongorestore?

Comment: Yes I did , for the dbBackUpPath I gave /home/backups/test  -- same as the one that I gave in the command line