# Export / Import Mongodb databases in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, import, export, database

Good Morning

I need to export / import a collection of a database MongoDB using Java.

I've seen that can be used Runtime.getRuntime (). Exec to use compandos to export and import databases, but not if they really work and are useful.

Anyone know any way to be able to make an export and import in MongoDB with Java

Comment: This might help you. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492008/how-to-import-export-all-collections-of-the-mongodb-database-using-mongodb-java)

Comment: Thank u very much!!